# python selenium close program with no traceback message

Tags: python, selenium

I've got a python (2.7.7) script where I'm automatically logging into a website, and then ending the program once the browser has been automatically closed. Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys

driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("www.url.com")

# Find username field and input the correct username
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("...")
inputElement.send_keys('...')


# Find the password field and input the correct password
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("...")
inputElement.send_keys('...')

# Simulate pushing the ENTER key
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

i = 0
while i < 3600:
    driver.title
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
b = browser.find_by_tag("body")
```

This works fine, except once the browser is closed and the program ends, I get a traceback message that displays in the python terminal:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path...", line 32, in 
    driver.title
  File "path...", line 194, in title
    resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)
  File "path...", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "path...", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchWindowException: Message: u'Unable to get browser'

I understand why this is displaying, but it is intentional behavior. I want the Python terminal to close right after the browser is closed, with no message.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, changing the end of the script to this accomplished what I was trying to do:

```
try:
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        driver.title
        time.sleep(1)
        i += 1
    b = browser.find_by_tag("body")

except:
    driver.close()
    subprocess.Popen("taskkill /f /IM IEDriverServer.exe")
```

Of course I had to import the subprocess library as well.